# I've defined a section - now I want to remove it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, templates, razor

Hi I've created a site with some views, within those views I've created a section title

```
@section title {
    My title.
}
```

On the layout page there is the line to render it.

```
 <h2>@RenderSection("title")</h2>
```

I'm thinking that it's no longer needed as the title is in the breadcrumb, so it's not really needed.
How do I remove the title, if I remove it from the layout page. Then it errors.
It seems to complain that it must be rendered somewhere.

I could put this in a hidden element or even a meta tag - but feels wrong.

I just want to see what it looks like - show the users but it could be something that comes back.

I just don't want to go through all the pages, removing this section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the problem? Use VisualStudion Search:

`Ctrl+F` -> **Entire Solution** -> `@section title`

Even more - you can use RegularExpressions in Search so you can do it like this:

```
@section title ?{.*(.*\n)+?.*}
```

Note that `.*` button pressed. That means that your search expression is Regex.
Now you can just replace your section across entire solution/project with this approach with Empty string.

[image]

Comment: Ok, that'll remove all the 'section title' but what if I want to bring them back?

Comment: @RichardHousham i think you should use Source Code Control System if you want make changes and then bring them back. I use git, but you can use what ever you want. TFS, SVN etc.

Comment: Yes see where your going here, guess I could just not a good idea if I've got to undo lots of changes. Maybe I'm asking too much from Razor here. Perhaps the thing to do is show them the changes with it hidden (using style) and then if they are happy remove (as per above) and commit.

Comment: @RichardHousham it could be possible. But don't you think that it's a dirty way?

Comment: true, sometimes code is dirty and you take what you can get.

Answer (score 1):

Use the overloaded method like this:

```
@RenderSection("title", required: false)
```

The required parameter indicates if the views have to have the title section. In your case it is not required so we pass a false.

Comment: Yeah, but if there is a section it'll still display it. I want to keep the section but not display it.